# How to start worker connector for mongodb in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, mongodb-kafka-connector

I use [this guide](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/getting-started-with-the-mongodb-connector-for-apache-kafka-and-mongodb-atlas) to setup mongodb connector.

The guide does not explain how to do the following, how to run connector.

> Start the Connect workers with that configuration. Connect will
> discover all connectors defined within those plugins.

All files of mongodb connector are placed in path:

**/home/user/Desktop/kafka-2.7.0-src/plugins/mongodbconnector**

Could you help?

Answer (score 0):

First, you've downloaded Kafka source code, not the binaries.

You could refer the [Kafka Connect User Guide](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#connect)

The `connect-*` scripts and property files are used to run Kafka Connect.

You'll need to add your plugins directory into the corresponding properties file `plugin.path` value